# Not able to login into Maximo Anywhere (work execution app) after adding new VIEW in app.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo, oslc, maximo-anywhere

I am trying to customize the Work Execution app by adding new view of Maximo object (SR). I had completed OSLC integration steps as mentioned by ibm http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.1/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.1/integration/t_ctr_int_mam.html?lang=en
after that I changed app.xml and added view definition as

```
<view id="SR.SRView" label="Service Request">
        <requiredResources>
            <requiredResource name="serviceRequest">
                <requiredAttribute name="description" />
            </requiredResource>
        </requiredResources>
        <list resource="serviceRequest" attribute="description">
            <sortOptions>
                <sortOption label="Item">
                    <sortAttribute name="description" direction="asc" />
                </sortOption>
            </sortOptions>
            <listItemTemplate layout="PlannedMaterialListItem">
                <listtext resourceAttribute="description" layoutInsertAt="item1" />
            </listItemTemplate>
        </list>
    </view>
```

and resource as

```
<resource providedBy="/oslc/sp/ServiceRequest"
        describedBy="http://jazz.net/ns/ism/sr/smarter_physical_infrastructure#ServiceRequest"
        name="serviceRequest" pageSize="20">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="description" describedByProperty="dcterms:description" />
        </attributes>
    </resource>
```

After building the application when I preview it in worklight studio I am getting below error

```
[WARNING ] Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project AnywhereWorkManager]OSLCGenericAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project AnywhereWorkManager]
Failed to parse JSON string
<H1>SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /maximoundefined has not been defined.</H1><BR><H3>SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle maxpc:9080 has not been defined.</H3><BR><I>IBM WebSphere Application Server</I>
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project AnywhereWorkManager]java.io.IOException: Unexpected character '<' on line 1, column 1java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse JSON string
<H1>SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /maximoundefined has not been defined.</H1><BR><H3>SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle maxpc:9080 has not been defined.</H3><BR><I>IBM WebSphere Application Server</I>
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.getResponseAsScriptable(HTTP.java:379)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.parseResponseContent(HTTP.java:316)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.execRequest(HTTP.java:173)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.invoke(HTTP.java:133)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext$DirectExecutorService.execute(InvocationContext.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.submit(InvocationContext.java:138)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContextManager.submitInvocation(InvocationContextManager.java:58)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:497)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$4.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:392)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:389)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:456)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:440)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1._c_anonymous_10(/integration.js:95)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1.call(/integration.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5CNewWorklight_Kep_SR_5CAnywhereWorkManager_5Cadapters_5COSLCGenericAdapter_OSLCGenericAdapter_impl_js_4._c_anonymous_2(C%3A%5CNewWorklight-Kep-SR%5CAnywhereWorkManager%5Cadapters%5COSLCGenericAdapter/OSLCGenericAdapter-impl.js:7)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5CNewWorklight_Kep_SR_5CAnywhereWorkManager_5Cadapters_5COSLCGenericAdapter_OSLCGenericAdapter_impl_js_4.call(C%3A%5CNewWorklight-Kep-SR%5CAnywhereWorkManager%5Cadapters%5COSLCGenericAdapter/OSLCGenericAdapter-impl.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaAdapter.doCall(JavaAdapter.java:603)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaAdapter.callMethod(JavaAdapter.java:578)
    at adapter1.invokeHttp(<adapter>)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.si.adapter.AdapterDependenciesImpl.invokeHttp(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.si.adapter.OSLCGenericAdapter.queryImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.si.adapter.OSLCGenericAdapter.query(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5CNewWorklight_Kep_SR_5CAnywhereWorkManager_5Cadapters_5COSLCGenericAdapter_OSLCGenericAdapter_impl_js_4._c_query_10(C%3A%5CNewWorklight-Kep-SR%5CAnywhereWorkManager%5Cadapters%5COSLCGenericAdapter/OSLCGenericAdapter-impl.js:183)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5CNewWorklight_Kep_SR_5CAnywhereWorkManager_5Cadapters_5COSLCGenericAdapter_OSLCGenericAdapter_impl_js_4.call(C%3A%5CNewWorklight-Kep-SR%5CAnywhereWorkManager%5Cadapters%5COSLCGenericAdapter/OSLCGenericAdapter-impl.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5CNewWorklight_Kep_SR_5CAnywhereWorkManager_5Cadapters_5COSLCGenericAdapter_OSLCGenericAdapter_impl_js_4.call(C%3A%5CNewWorklight-Kep-SR%5CAnywhereWorkManager%5Cadapters%5COSLCGenericAdapter/OSLCGenericAdapter-impl.js)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:240)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:214)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:194)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal$1RunnableWrapper.run(ProjectLocal.java:267)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected character '<' on line 1, column 1
    at com.ibm.json.java.internal.Tokenizer.next(Tokenizer.java:129)
    at com.ibm.json.java.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:57)
    at com.ibm.json.java.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:47)
    at com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject.parse(JSONObject.java:79)
    at com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject.parse(JSONObject.java:91)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.getResponseAsScriptable(HTTP.java:376)
    ... 63 more
```

Note that I am able to get result by below URL in browser.

[http://maxpc:9080/maximo/oslc/os/oslcsrequest?_lid=maxadmin&_lpwd=maxadmin
]

I appreciate any help.

Adaptor Code: (XML)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<wl:adapter xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration" 
    xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    name="OSLCGenericAdapter">

    <displayName>OSLCGenericAdapter</displayName>
    <description>OSLCGenericAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType" cookiePolicy="IGNORE_COOKIES">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>maxpc</domain>
            <port>9080</port>           
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="120" />
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="create" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest" />
    <procedure name="deleteResource" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest"/>
    <procedure name="get" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest"/>
    <procedure name="getResource" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest"/>
    <procedure name="query" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest" connectAs="endUser" requestTimeoutInSeconds="360"/>
    <procedure name="insertResource" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest" connectAs="endUser"/>
    <procedure name="update"  securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest"/>
    <procedure name="updateResource" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest" connectAs="endUser"/>
    <!-- getProperties is used before authentication, we need to keep it unprotected -->
    <procedure name="getProperties" securityTest="wl_unprotected" connectAs="endUser"/>
    <procedure name="login" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest" connectAs="endUser"/>
    <procedure name="logout" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest" connectAs="endUser"/>
    <procedure name="getActiveUserIdentity" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest" connectAs="endUser"/>
    <procedure name="changePassword" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest" connectAs="endUser"/>
    <procedure name="noSessionChangePassword" securityTest="wl_unprotected" connectAs="endUser"/>

    <!-- when getSecurityData is called by the client, we initiate the security test to see if we are authenticated? -->
    <procedure name="getSecretData" securityTest="CustomAdapter-securityTest"/>
    <!-- query2 is a temporary procedure for testing authentication unique user data -->
    <procedure name="query2" />

    <!--
        get server datetime and register before/after requesting server's information. 
        It will be used for calibrating the delta between server and device clocks   
     -->
    <procedure name="getServerDate" securityTest="wl_unprotected" connectAs="endUser"/>



</wl:adapter>
```

Adaptor Impl

```
    var adapterDependenciesImpl = {
    encodeURI : function(uri) {
        return encodeURI(uri);
    },
    invokeHttp : function(input) {
        WL.Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(input));
        return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    },
    debug : function(input) {
        WL.Logger.debug(input);
    }
};

var adapterDependencies = com.ibm.tivoli.si.adapter
        .JsAdapterDependencies(adapterDependenciesImpl);
var adapterImpl = com.ibm.tivoli.si.adapter.OSLCGenericAdapter
        .createOSLCGenericAdapter(adapterDependencies);
/**
 * WL.Server.invokeHttp(parameters) accepts the following json object as an
 * argument:
 *  { // Mandatory method : 'get' , 'post', 'delete' , 'put' or 'head' path:
 * value,
 *  // Optional returnedContentType: any known mime-type or one of "json",
 * "css", "csv", "javascript", "plain", "xml", "html" returnedContentEncoding :
 * 'encoding', parameters: {name1: value1, ... }, headers: {name1: value1, ... },
 * cookies: {name1: value1, ... }, body: { contentType: 'text/xml;
 * charset=utf-8' or similar value, content: stringValue }, transformation: {
 * type: 'default', or 'xslFile', xslFile: fileName } }
 */

function login(user, pwd, langcode) {
    var credentials = adapterImpl.base64EncodeCredentials(user, pwd);

    path = getBasePath() + 'login';

    var heardervalue = null;
    if(langcode == null)
    {
        heardervalue= {
            'maxauth' : credentials,
            'accept' : 'application/json'
        }
    }
    else
    {
        heardervalue= {
            'maxauth' : credentials,
            'accept' : 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language' : langcode
        }
    };      


    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : path,
        headers : heardervalue
    };
    try {
        var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

        if (response['statusCode'] == 200) {
            var cookies = response['responseHeaders']['Set-Cookie'];
            if (!cookies) {
                throw "No jsessionid returned";
            }
            var jsessionid = cookies.split(';')[0].split('=')[1];
            WL.Logger.debug(jsessionid);
            return {
                sessionid : jsessionid
            };
        }
        WL.Logger.debug(response);
        return {
            isSuccessful : false,
            errors : [ response["oslc:Error"] ]
        };
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

function logout(jsessionid) {
    path = getBasePath() + 'logout';

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : path,
        cookies : {
            'JSESSIONID' : jsessionid
        },
        headers : {
            'accept' : 'application/json',
            'Cookie' : 'JSESSIONID=' + jsessionid
        }
    };

    try {
        WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

    } catch (e) {
        WL.Logger.error(e);
    }
    return {
        isSuccessful : true
    };
}

function getActiveUserIdentity() {
    return WL.Server.getActiveUser();
}

function create(params) {
    if (params == null) {
        return {};
    }

    path = getBasePath();

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : path,
        body : {
            contentType : 'json; charset=utf-8',
            content : params.resource
        },
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

function deleteResource(params) {
    if (params == null) {
        return '';
    }
    path = getBasePath();
    path = path + '/' + params.id;

    var input = {
        method : 'delete',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : path
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

function get(params) {
    if (params == null) {
        return {};
    }

    path = getBasePath();
    path = path + '/' + params.id;

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : path
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

function query(params) {
    var errors = [];
    if (null == params) {
        errors.push("No parameter present.");
    } else {
        if (null == params.url)
            errors.push("Must have url parameter.");
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Required parameter not present
        return resp = {
            "isSuccessful" : "false",
            "errors" : errors
        };
    }
    var response = adapterImpl.query(params);
    if ("oslc:Error" in response) {
        return {
            isSuccessful : false,
            errors : [ response["oslc:Error"] ]
        };
    }
    return response;
}

function getResource(params) {
    var errors = [];
    if (null == params) {
        errors.push("No parameter present.");
    } else {
        if (null == params.url)
            errors.push("Must have url parameter.");
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Required parameter not present
        return resp = {
            "isSuccessful" : "false",
            "errors" : errors
        };
    }

    var returnValue = adapterImpl.getResource(params);
    return returnValue;
}

function insertResource(params) {
    var errors = [];
    if (null == params) {
        errors.push("No parameter present.");
    } else {
        if (null == params.url)
            errors.push("Must have url parameter.");
        if (null == params.payload)
            errors.push("Must have payload parameter.");
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Required parameter not present
        return resp = {
            "isSuccessful" : false,
            "errors" : errors
        };
    }
    var response = adapterImpl.insertResource(params);
    if ("oslc:Error" in response) {
        return {
            isSuccessful : false,
            responseHeaders: response.responseHeaders,
            errors : [ response["oslc:Error"] ]
        };
    }
    return response;
}
function updateResource(params) {
    var errors = [];
    if (null == params) {
        errors.push("No parameter present.");
    } else {
        if (null == params.url)
            errors.push("Must have url parameter.");
        if (null == params.payload)
            errors.push("Must have payload parameter.");
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Required parameter not present
        return {
            "isSuccessful" : "false",
            "errors" : errors
        };
    }

    var response = adapterImpl.updateResource(params);
    if ("oslc:Error" in response) {
        return {
            isSuccessful : false,
            responseHeaders: response.responseHeaders,
            errors : [ response["oslc:Error"] ]
        };
    }
    return response;
}

function noSessionChangePassword(params){
    return  changePassword(params);
}

function changePassword(params) {
    var errors = [];
    if (null == params) {
        errors.push("No parameter . ");
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Required parameter not present
        return resp = {
            "isSuccessful" : "false",
            "errors" : errors
        };
    }

    var returnValue = adapterImpl.changePassword(params);
    return returnValue;
}

function update(params) {
    if (params == null) {
        return {};
    }

    path = getBasePath();
    path = path + '/' + params.id;

    var input = {
        method : 'put',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : path,
        body : {
            contentType : 'json; charset=utf-8',
            content : params.resource
        },
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

function getProperties(params) {
    var resp = {};
    for(var index in params.propertyNames){
        var name = params.propertyNames[index];
        resp[name] = WL.Server.configuration[name];
    }
    return {"properties" : resp};
}

function getBasePath() {
    var si_platform_context=WL.Server.configuration['si.platform.context'];

    if (null == si_platform_context || '' == si_platform_context ) {
        return 'maximo/oslc/';
    } 

    //WL.Logger.log("++++ worklight property [si.maximo.context]=[" + WL.Server.configuration['si.maximo.context'] + "]");
    return si_platform_context + '/oslc/';
}

/**
 * Procedures to support query2
 * 
 * @param params
 * @returns
 */
function getURLPath(params) {
    var path = getBasePath();
    path += "os/oslcwodetail/?oslc.pageSize=20&oslc.select="
            + params.oslcSelect;
    return path;
}

/**
 * Procedure to support query2
 * 
 * @returns {___anonymous4713_4741}
 */
function getSecretData() {
    var activeuser = WL.Server.getActiveUser();
    var activeuserString = JSON.stringify(activeuser);
    WL.Logger.debug("OSLCADAPTER: get secret data - current identity object ="
            + activeuserString);
    return {
        secretData : '123456'
    };
}

// ==================== Authentication Functions =======================//

/**
 * TODO: Convert this procedure to java
 * 
 * WL.Logger.debug writes to the WL Server message.log and console.log
 * 
 */
function query2(params) {
    if (null == params || null == params.resource || null == params.queryBase
            || null == params.oslcSelect) {
        return {};
    }

    WL.Logger.debug("OSLC Adapter - query2 :: Entering");

    // Attempting to get the session token from the WL getActiveUser API
    var activeuser = WL.Server.getActiveUser();
    var activeuserString = JSON.stringify(activeuser);
    var parsestring = JSON.parse(activeuserString);
    var activeusercookies = parsestring["attributes"]["JSESSIONID"];

    var stringparams = JSON.stringify(params);

    WL.Logger.debug("OSLC ADAPTER: query2 - WL.Server.getActiveUser  ["
            + activeuserString + "]");
    WL.Logger.debug("OSLC ADAPTER: query2 - activeusercookies        ["
            + activeusercookies + "]");
    WL.Logger.debug("OSLC ADAPTER: query2 - input string             ["
            + stringparams + "]");

    // Attempt to get the session token from the Client/device params
    var parse2 = JSON.parse(stringparams);
    var jsessionidobj = parse2["myjsessionidobj"];

    // WL.Logger.debug("OSLC ADAPTER: query2 - input string jsessionidobj [" +
    // JSON.stringify(jsessionidobj) + "]");
    var token = jsessionidobj.split("=")[1];
    var cookie = {
        "JSESSIONID" : token
    };

    WL.Logger.debug("OSLC ADAPTER: query2 - send token  ["
            + JSON.stringify(token) + "]");
    WL.Logger.debug("OSLC ADAPTER: query2 - send cookie ["
            + JSON.stringify(cookie) + "]");

    path = getURLPath(params);
    path = encodeURI(path);

    WL.Logger.debug("OSLC ADAPTER: query2 - path =[" + path + "]");

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : path,
        cookies : cookie
    };

    WL.Logger.debug("OSLC ADAPTER: query2 - send to MAXIMO input ="
            + JSON.stringify(input));

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}


/**
 * Specific function to ping server and get Date from it. Also calculates
 * network latency based on before/after datetime when requesting the server
 */
function getServerDate(params) {

    WL.Logger.debug("Server clock synchronization::init");

    path = getBasePath();

    if (path.lastIndexOf('/') == path.length - 1) { // verify if last char is
                                                    // '/' , then remove it
        path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"));
    }

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : path,
        //cookies : {
        //  'JSESSIONID' : params.jsessionid
        //},
        headers : {
            'accept' : 'application/json',
            'Cookie' : params.cookie
        }
    };

    WL.Logger.debug("Server clock synchronization::path::" + path);

    try {

        var befInvoke = Date.parse(new Date().toUTCString());
        var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
        var aftInvoke = Date.parse(new Date().toUTCString());

        if (response['statusCode'] == 200) {
            var srvDate = response['responseHeaders']['Date'];

            WL.Logger.debug(srvDate);

            return {
                beforeInvoke : befInvoke,
                afterInvoke : aftInvoke,
                serverDate : srvDate
            };
        }
        WL.Logger.debug(response);
        return {
            isSuccessful : false,
            errors : [ response["oslc:Error"] ]
        };
    } catch (e) {
        WL.Logger.debug("Server clock synchronization::Error::" + e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is about the adapter code. Where is the adapter code. You should also mention your Worklight version...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using worklight 6.0, Maximo anywhere 7.5, and websphere 8.5 liberty profile. And OSLC generic adaptor. I will edit the post and add adaptor code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the querybase specifier for this resource.  Without this information, we can't determine which URL to go to to retrieve the new SR objects.

It should look something like this under the new resource section:

```
    <queryBases>
        <queryBase name="getSR" queryUri="/oslc/os/<yournewOSURL>"/>
    </queryBases>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot scott, it worked but now I am getting below error on console and SR view is not opening, its waiting on login screen. Any clue?

Comment: [WARNING ] Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}

Comment: No I'm not sure on this one.  Can you open another question, tag it with maximoanywhere and attach the full console log and maybe some screenshots of what you're trying to accomplish with your customization?  I'll see if I can figure out what's wrong.